# Upload one file to multi folder google driver via API with python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I want to upload a file to multi folder google driver via API but only one file will be save, not each file for each folder. (1 file in serveral folder)

Example using by hand: [Add the Same File to Multiple Folders in Google Drive without Copying](https://www.labnol.org/internet/add-files-multiple-drive-folders/28715/)

Could you please help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [inserting a file in a folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder#inserting_a_file_in_a_folder), you need to specify the correct folder ID in the `parents` property of the file. Using Python:

```
folder_id = '0BwwA4oUTeiV1TGRPeTVjaWRDY1E'
file_metadata = {
  'name' : 'photo.jpg',
  'parents': [ folder_id ]
}
media = MediaFileUpload('files/photo.jpg',
                        mimetype='image/jpeg',
                        resumable=True)
file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                    media_body=media,
                                    fields='id').execute()
print 'File ID: %s' % file.get('id')
```

As further mentioned in [Files: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert), setting the `parents[]` property in the request body will put the file in all of the provided folders. If no folders are provided in `parents[]` field, the file will be placed in the default root folder.

Hope that helps!